# using jquery ui autocomplete but styles hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I ma using jquery UI auto complete and i am getting the results, the only problem i am getting the results

> http://prntscr.com/rsm946

not sure why it is not display, the `json` is coming as correct

**my JSOn**

```
[{"name":"author","type":"U","status":"0","owner":"dbo"},{"name":"author_dates","type":"U","status":"0","owner":"dbo"}] 

$("#student").autocomplete(
    {
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "search.cfc?method=searchByName&returnformat=json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        search: request.term,
        maxRows: 10
    },
    success: function(data) {
      response($.map(data, function(item) {
         return { 
            label: item.label, value: item.label 
         };
      }));
    }
    })
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#submit').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: please give jsfiddle

Comment: I suspect you are rendering the items with an incorrect format. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: for jquery ui, please see edit

Comment: I do not see `label` or `value` in your JSON Object. I only see `name`, `type`, `status`, `owner`. So your `.map()` is going to create a number of empty elements.

Comment: so what is the fix

Comment: @SignUp correct your map to map items in your Object properly.

Comment: thanks for the fix, i found the issue it needs a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following:

```
$("#student").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("search.cfc", {
      method: "searchByName",
      returnformat: "json",
      search: request.term,
      maxRows: 10
    }, function(data) {
      response($.map(data, (item) => {
        return $.extend(item, {
          label: item.name,
          value: item.name,
        });
      }));
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#submit').css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object attribute is name, not label so u should write name despide of label

```
$("#student").autocomplete(
{
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({
    url: "search.cfc?method=searchByName&returnformat=json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
    search: request.term,
    maxRows: 10
},
success: function(data) {
  response($.map(data, function(item) {
     return { 
        label: item.name, value: item.name
     };
  }));
}
})
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#submit').css("display", "block");
}
```

});